# How to have the echo command process newline characters?

Tags: command-line, echo

I find that when running `:echo message` with a message variable that contains newlines, it displays the newline character as `^@`.  Often I'd prefer it to actually be split on a new line though.  Do I have to split up the string manually and then make multiple calls to echo or is there a simpler way to do that?

edit:
Here's an example that reproduces what I'm talking about: `:echom "foo\nbar"`.  I'm running gvim on windows

Comment: Can you be more specific about those newlines. Where is the text coming from. Are you on *nix or Windows? (Can't be regular, multi-line Vim text because that should work just fine.)

Comment: Ok I updated the question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You originally mention `:echo` but  based on your example it's `:echom` that is causing you issues so assuming that's right...

Some choices depending on your specific needs (e.g. do you care about the message being saved to the message history)...

```
:echo "foo\nbar"

:echon "foo\nbar"

:echom "foo" | echom "bar"
```

All of these will produce

```
foo
bar
```

Likely due to it's primary purpose being to print messages to be read by the user interactively, `echom` parses things a bit differently from the others. "Unprintable characters are displayed not interpreted". (Similar to the `strtrans()` function which also prints newlines as `^@`).

Comment: Ohh I didn't realize this behaviour was specific to `echom`.  Thanks.

Comment: @SteveVermeulen No problem. Yeah I think the primary use case for `echom`, in contrast to the others, is real-time display of short messages for users. Thus you get qualities like avoiding non-printing chars and discouraging multi-line output.

Answer (score 0):

Although the question is about `echo` or `echomsg`, from some reason `echoerr` acts differently, so in addition to [the 1st answer given](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/18204/6411), it may worth noting `echomsg`'s caveats:

If you want to display an error with new lines, this won't work:

```
echoerr 'line 1 here\n' .
 \ 'line 2 there'
```

Removing the `.` won't help. Doing this:

```
echoerr 'line 1 here'
echoerr 'line 2 there'
```

Is a bit better - but the output looks like this:

```
Error detected while processing function 212:
line   18:
line 1 here
Press ENTER or type command to continue
Error detected while processing function 212:
line   19:
line 2 there
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

And this is probably not what one would desire - having to press these `ENTER` keys.

Hence, the probably best solution is:

```
let v:errmsg = "line 1 here\n" .
  \ "line 2 there"
echo v:errmsg
```

Answer (score 0):

Vim will automatically soft-wrap echoed lines longer than `&columns`. Due to this perk, the following does work, although the formatting would break on screen resizes.

```
let msg = "Hello"

echoerr msg . repeat(" ", &columns - len(msg)) . msg
```

The snippet should output

```
Hello
Hello
```

You probably could create a helper function to calculate that automatically

```
function! EchoErrMsg(msg)
  if type(a:msg) == type("")
    let msg = split(a:msg, "\n")
  elseif type(a:msg) == type([])
    let msg = a:msg
  else
    throw "Expecting list or string as input"
  endif

  if len(msg) == 1
    let str_msg = msg[0]
  else
    for i in range(0, len(msg) - 1)
      let msg_len = len(msg[i])
      if msg_len < &columns
        let msg[i] = msg[i] . repeat(" ", &columns - (msg_len + 1))
      endif
    endfor
    let str_msg = join(msg, " ")
  endif

  echoerr str_msg
endfun
```

Note that this is a hack. Ideally `echom` would be modified in the Vim source or a new message-related could be created to allow for the same syntax `echon`.

Alternatively, if you simply want to display multiple lines as *if it were* an error, use `echohl Error`. Albeit simpler, unlike `echomsg` or `echoerr`, this will not save the output to the message history.

```
echohl Error
echon "Line 1\nLine 2"
echohl NONE
```